# Generate magnetic field from card stripe wav or text data

Tags: electromagnetism

Internet has a couple of answers about reading and decoding card magnetic stripe. I have another question -- how can I create magnetic field from stored stripe data?

I want to take the data that I've read from a magnetic stripe card and use it to generate the equivalent sequence of magnetic fields in another place.

Comment: No need, the stripe is magnetically encoded and comes with its own magnetic field.

Comment: There is very little field, you can't use that for anything.

Comment: I have decoded data from stripe as text string. For example: ";1234 5678?"

Comment: Are you trying to write data to another card by generating a strong field? I think this question needs a bit more clarification.

Comment: No, I am not. And I am not going to deal with bank cards. And not going to create any criminal activity (I think I need to write this here). I want to generate field for simple card reader. As I know simple card reader have magnetic head (just like old casette recorder have). And I know that possible to generate field for this reader. So I want to know how to do it.

Comment: @PeterHorvath If you couldn't use it for anything then you couldn't read the magnetic stripe.

Comment: I'm still unclear on what it is you're asking.  "how can I create magnetic field from stored stripe data?"  The data is stored magnetically, it already has a magnetic field that you can decode with an appropriate read head.  There's no need to generate a magnetic field unless you are trying to write data to the stripe.

Comment: Ok, you want a stationary "card" to play back card data, i.e. no swipe motion.  You can do this with a thin metal strip with a coil of wire on the end.  An "extended" electromagnet of sorts.